# Finding possible second position of knight with Ruby

Tags: ruby

[image]

In the above image the second mouse coordinate is [2,1].

I can find possible first move of knight movement by following.

```
[1,-1].product([2,-2])+[2,-2].product([1,-1])
=> [[1, 2], [1, -2], [-1, 2], [-1, -2], [2, 1], [2, -1], [-2, 1], [-2, -1]]
```

In order to find the second move I found that I need to find combination of sum of the above array.

For example from [0,0] to [2,0], you can add [1,2]+[1,-2] to get [2,0].

Now I am wondering how to sum two arrays to find all possible second position.

I appreciate any inputs.

UPDATE

```
([1,-1].product([2,-2])+[2,-2].product([1,-1])).combination(2).to_a
=> [[[1, 2], [1, -2]], [[1, 2], [-1, 2]], [[1, 2], [-1, -2]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], 
[[1, 2], [2, -1]], [[1, 2], [-2, 1]], [[1, 2], [-2, -1]], [[1, -2], [-1, 2]], 
[[1, -2], [-1, -2]], [[1, -2], [2, 1]], [[1, -2], [2, -1]], [[1, -2], [-2, 1]], 
[[1, -2], [-2, -1]], [[-1, 2], [-1, -2]], [[-1, 2], [2, 1]], [[-1, 2], [2, -1]], 
[[-1, 2], [-2, 1]], [[-1, 2], [-2, -1]], [[-1, -2], [2, 1]], [[-1, -2], [2, -1]], 
[[-1, -2], [-2, 1]], [[-1, -2], [-2, -1]], [[2, 1], [2, -1]], [[2, 1], [-2, 1]], 
[[2, 1], [-2, -1]], [[2, -1], [-2, 1]], [[2, -1], [-2, -1]], [[-2, 1], [-2, -1]]]
```

Now I need to add arrays in the same array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are correct you want to sum all *combinations* of the two arrays, removing duplicates. Hint: use [Array#combination](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQygQwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ruby-doc.org%2Fcore-2.1.1%2FArray.html%23method-i-combination&ei=tb9RU5qIEIirsQSnooCoDQ&usg=AFQjCNGRcrfAMgrNURnG10SXMntZzQfj8Q&bvm=bv.65058239,d.cWc).

Comment: Consider building an oct tree where each depth level shows the next possible set of moves.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct.

```
([1,-1].product([2,-2])+[2,-2].product([1,-1])).combination(2).map{|x| x.map{|y|
 y.inject(:+)}}.uniq
=> [[3, -1], [3, 1], [3, -3], [3, 3], [-1, 1], [-1, -3], [-1, 3], [-1, -1], 
[1, -3], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-3, 3], [-3, 1], [-3, -1], [-3, -3]]
```